# How to allocate more memory in Python Spyder

Tags: python, memory

I have seen multiple questions on this subject but haven't seen a single answer to how to actually fix it other than attempting a different form of script.

Here is a simplified example. I am running this in an iPython console in Spyder with Python 2.7:

```
import numpy as np
X = np.zeros([1000, 1000, 50]) #works just fine
X = np.zeros([1000, 1000, 100]) #creates a MemoryError
```

I went to Windows Task Manager and see that Python is only using ~260 MB out of the total 2 GB that my PC has. I know that I need to save a lot of RAM for system processes, but come on, I can spare more memory than this for Python. Knowing that I need to not set it too high in order to avoid catastrophic system damage, where in Spyder or Python itself can I go to increase the maximum memory allowed?

Comment: What version, *exactly*, of Python are you using? Is it a 32-bit version of Python? What does `import sys; print(sys.maxsize)` give you? There is no "setting" of the maximum amount of memory Python will use, that is up to the OS. And this has nothing to do with Spyder.

Comment: I am running Python 2.7.10, 32-bit. sys.maxsize gives: 2147483647. Am I locked into this maxsize with this version of Python?

Comment: Yes, a 32bit process will have at most 4 gigabytes of address space, which limits your memory allocation, but many OS have a different limit, I believe Window's is quite restrictive. Use a 64bit version of Python.